# Ruby on Rails: Gem to design emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rubygems, rich-text-editor

In my RoR application, I am allowing users to design and send emails. Currently, I am using trix rich text editor to allow them to change the format of the text in the email, but is there a way of allowing the users to design the emails in terms of its background colour, font, layout, etc.?

So is there a gem or WYSIWYG editor that would allow the user to design their emails in a similar way to Outlook?

[image]

I have looked at Trix, Bootsy, and Froala but none of them seem to provide the same number of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) is one of those that do what you need. Basically, what you are looking for is a WYSIWYG HTML editor and there are quite a few out there.